# Сделать(,) как я

Tags: пунктуация, как, обороты-с-как, оборот-с-как

Подскажите, пожалуйста, **чем является** **"как я"** в предложении — сравнительным оборотом или сочетанием, тесно связанным со сказуемым — и нужно ли его **обособление**.